# I need help mocking a method in my c# project

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm fairly new to this TDD and I'm lost with this at the moment.

I'm trying to use .Setup to get the product by ID of 99 and check it's actually returned in .Returns(saveProduct), which causes me the error below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn632.png)

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class ProductControllerTests
{
    private Mock<ICart> cartMock;
    private Mock<IProductRepository> productRepositoryMock;
    private Mock<IOrderRepository> orderRepositoryMock;
    private Mock<IProductService> productServiceMock;
    private Mock<ILanguageService> languageServiceMock;
    private Mock<IStringLocalizer<ProductService>> stringLocalizerMock;
    private ProductViewModel product;

    private ProductController productController;

    public ProductControllerTests()
    {
        //setup
        product = new ProductViewModel();
        cartMock = new Mock<ICart>();
        productRepositoryMock = new Mock<IProductRepository>();
        orderRepositoryMock = new Mock<IOrderRepository>();
        stringLocalizerMock = new Mock<IStringLocalizer<ProductService>>();
        productServiceMock = new Mock<IProductService>();
        languageServiceMock = new Mock<ILanguageService>();
        productController = new ProductController(productServiceMock.Object, languageServiceMock.Object);

    }

    [Fact]
    public void CreateValidModelState() // MOCKED
    {
        // Act
        ProductService productService = new ProductService(cartMock.Object, productRepositoryMock.Object, orderRepositoryMock.Object, stringLocalizerMock.Object);

        productController = new ProductController(productService, languageServiceMock.Object);

        productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.SaveProduct(product)); //It works without this?!? what's it FOR!?

        //Arranje


        product.Id = 99;
        product.Name = "Test box";
        product.Description = "The best box ever.";
        product.Details = "Toss it and see if it gets back.";
        product.Stock = "9000";
        product.Price = "9000";

        var saveProduct = productController.Create(product);


        //productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetProductById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(saveProduct);
        //productServiceMock.SetupGet(x => x.GetProductById(99)).Returns("Test box");

        //var expectedProduct = productServiceMock.GetProduct(1);

        Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(saveProduct);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide the error traceback as text, not as a picture. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of room for improvement in your code snippet.

First, you create private members but then you over write the variable name with local variables.

The idea behind mocking is that when you mock an interface you can Setup its' methods to return whatever you wish them to return. So in your case

```
productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetProductById(99)).Returns(saveProduct);
```

the line above means that wherever in your controller you have the GetProductById(int) method is called with 99 as a parameter, the method will return the saveProduct object.

You could also write the Setup like

```
productServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetProductById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(saveProduct);
```

In this case wherever in your controller the GetProductById() method is called, no matter what is the parameter passed, you will get the saveProductObject.

In this test you have written I can not see any value. What I mean is that create a controller, you create the saveProduct and then you assert it is not null. Of course it is not null, because you populated above.

It would make sense to actually use one of your controllers methods that you know that the GetByUserId() method is used. Then make an assertion upon the return object based on the methods logic.

**---Update---**

Imagine you have a handler

```
public class HandlerExample {

    private IInjectedService _injectedService;

    public HandlerExample(IInjectedService injectedService){
        _injectedService = injectedService;
    }

    public int Handle(testNumber)
    {
        var serviceResponse = _injectedService.TestMethod(testNumber);

        if(serviceResponse)
            return 1;

        return 2;   
    }
}
```

And your interface looks like

```
public interface IInjectedService
{
    bool TestMethod(int testNumber);
}
```

I won't give any example on the implementation here because it is not relevant. Your test method would then make sense to be like

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    mockedInjectedService = new Mock<IInjectedService>();
    mockedInjectedService.Setup(x => x.TestMethod(99)).Returns(true);

    var handler = new Handler(mockedInjectedService.Object);

    var sut = handler.Handle(99);

    Assert.Equal(sut, 1);
}
```

sut is a convention for "system under test"

Comment: Stelios, thank you a lot for taking your time to enlighten me in this topic =) 


I have added the private members. I thought there was a character limit, because my code was getting out of format here when everything was posted.

I have tried the .Setup as you suggested and same error happens.

I know the test  as a whole  has no value, because it is to be finished, this is one of my first mocks and all this is supposed to do is make sure the Created product is returned.

I'll try to use a method from another controller later to see if the product was saved.

Comment: @ClarkSwanson I have updated my answer. If you need any more help let me know. I hope it clarifies for you how mock is working.

Comment: Hey, I updated it and a second question follows, how come it passes without the .Setup()?

Comment: @ClarkSwanson it was passing because the assertion was wrong. I updated the answer. We were checking if true. We should check if sut is 1 or 2 depending if the mocked method was setup properly or not. Test again and it will not pass if you do not setup.